# Find deepest nested path?

Tags: python, directory

Is there a way to find the deepest nested path with python?

Like say if you had a list of directories like

/cats/xmas/1.jpg
/cats/beach/2.jpg
/dogs/xmas/2010/1.jpg

it would print 
/dogs/xmas/2010/1.jpg

as being the longest path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like

```
def longest_path( paths ):
    key = lambda path:path.count('/')
    return max(paths, key=key)
```

You should use [`os.path.normpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) on the paths before counting.

I guess on Windows this could get a bit tricky since the path separator can be either \ or / ... the code below lets `os.path.split` figure it out:

```
import os.path
def nesting(path):
    """ counts how often `os.path.split` works on `path` """
    c = 0
    head = tail = path
    while head and tail:
        head, tail = os.path.split(head)
        c +=1
    return c

def longest_path( paths ):
        return max(paths, key=nesting)
```

Since you're looking for the deepest path, it has to be a folder that has no subfolders! You can get it like this:

```
def find_leafes( root ):
    """ finds folders with no subfolders """
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        if not dirs: # can't go deeper
            yield root

print longest_path(find_leafes( root ))
```

Comment: or even faster: key = lambda path: path.count('/')

Comment: so would I need to use os.walk and append to a list before passing to your longest_path function?

Comment: @Kevin Postal: You have to create a list of paths that have no subfolders.

Comment: @JochenRitzel I think you meant [leaves](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leaves)?

Answer (score 1):

So far this seems to be working

```
import os,sys

list = []
search_path = 'C:\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\'

def nesting(path):
    """ counts how often `os.path.split` works on `path` """
    c = 0
    head = tail = path
    while head and tail:
        head, tail = os.path.split(head)
        c +=1
    return c

def longest_path( paths ):
        return max(paths, key=nesting)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):
   for name in files:       
       filename = os.path.join(root, name)
       sys.stdout.write('.')
       list.append(filename)

print longest_path(list)
```

Thanks so much guys!